# Как конвертировать steamID64 в SteamID3?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, steam-web-api

У меня нету кода, могу предоставить только код на получение этих данных но он думаю, не сильно нужен в данном вопросе.

По примеру, мне нужно что-то похожее на вот такой конвертор: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31270278/convert-steamid64-to-steamid попробуйте

Comment: @Nilsan спасибо, сейчас попробую - думаю это то что мне нужно!

Comment: @Nilsan это было близко, но во первых автор допустил ошибку в ответе, так как в документации сказано что там и как, а во вторых, этот пример работает только для его id а значит, что не работает... Но близко

Comment: @Nilsan вы были очень близко к решению, если убрать parseInt я точно получу STEAM_0:1:65694773 - А это близко к решению полному точно

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```html
<?php

/**
 * Class SteamID
 * Simple PHP SteamID converter class that converts between SteamID's and Steam CommunityID's
 *
 * @author Callum Thomson <callum@callumthomson.co.uk>
 * @version 3.0.0
 */
class SteamIDConverter {
    /**
  * Make a decision based on the input which conversion function should be run and then call it with the data.
  *
     * @param $id SteamID or CommunityID
  * @return string Converted ID
     */
    public static function convert($id)
 {
  if(strpos($id, 'STEAM')===false) 
  { // It's a CommunityID
   return self::getIDFromCommunity($id);
  }
  else
  { // It's a SteamID
   return self::getCommunityFromID($id);
  }
 }
    /**
  * Convert SteamID into a CommunityID
  *
     * @param $id SteamID
     * @return string CommunityID
     */
    private  static function getCommunityFromID($id)
 {
  $accountarray = explode(":", $id);
  $idnum   = $accountarray[1];
  $accountnum  = $accountarray[2];
  $constant  = '76561197960265728';
  $number   = bcadd(bcmul($accountnum, 2), bcadd($idnum, $constant)); // ($accountnum *2) + ($idnum + $constant)
  return $number;
 }
    /**
  * Convert CommunityID to SteamID
  *
     * @param $id CommunityID
     * @return string SteamID
     */
    private static function getIDFromCommunity($id)
 {
  $idnum  = '0';
  $accnum  = '0';
  $constant = '76561197960265728';
  if(bcmod($id, '2')==0)
  {
   $idnum = '0';
   $temp = bcsub($id, $constant);
  }
  else
  {
   $idnum = '1';
   $temp = bcsub($id,bcadd($constant, '1'));
  }
  $accnum = bcdiv($temp, '2');
  return   "STEAM_0:".$idnum.":".number_format($accnum, 0, '', '');
 }
}

echo SteamIDConverter::convert('76561198091655275');
```

Нашел [такую штуку](https://github.com/callumthomson/steamid-converter) на гитхабе, потестил на парочке ID вроде верный результат, потестируйте

Comment: STEAM_0:0:-598980132864 вот мой steamId - `76561198091655275`

Comment: `1197960265728` - хотелось бы уточнить, что это за число?

Comment: тут `$steamY` после `parseInt(...)`  0 - я в php не мастер, не могу понять почему 0, если бы не 0 - все бы работало

Comment: Поменял ответ, потестируйте

Comment: да, выводит тот же результат, что и ваш ответ, только теперь мне ничего не понятно )) но работает, осталось только понять как получить [U:1:131389547]

Comment: меня больше всего интересует [U:1:131389547] -> 131389547 вот это значение

Comment: https://github.com/Groruk/SteamID - во, прям рабочее всё :-)